# Apache Airflow environment setup

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Can a single installation of Apache Airflow be used to handle multiple environments? eg. Dev, QA1, QA2, and Production (if so please guide) or do I need to have a separate install for each? What would be the best design considering maintenance of all environments.

Comment: Thanks for down vote. I'm asking about the experience (learn, share and build) and you want it to be (learn [dont ask], share and build) its fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever you want. If you want to keep a single Airflow installation to handle different environments, you could switch connections or Airflow variables according to the environment.

At the end of the day DAGs are written in Python so you're really flexible.